# SQL Index for faster searching and updating

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

looking for a bit of advice on SQL indexing.
Whats the best type of index to create on a non-unique field to allow for faster searching and updating? I created a non-clustered index which speeded it up slightly but not much.

As for the system, (and please dont laugh) ive been asked to amend a clients Access 2003 / SQL 2008 back end, I dont want to re-write the whole thing (ive to upgrade to .net next year anyway) and the seraching is done via VBA modules.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Metrics Metrics Metrics**

Use the profiler to determine what aspects are slow. Then worry about indexing strategy specifically to address those requirements. There usually is no magic bullet.